# Creating input parameters and using java web service function in ASP.NET Web API

Tags: java, c#, asp.net, web-services

I have created a java web service that does addition function. I also have created an ASP.NET Web API which calls the java web service and displays the result. Lets say i typed in `http://localhost:8080/addition/9/6` as the URL with input parameters that the java web service function should add. I get the output data as `{"firstNumber":9,"secondNumber":6,"sum":15}`. When i run my ASP.NET Web API, i will be redirected to `http://localhost:55223/` and i will get the output data as `{"firstNumber":9,"secondNumber":6,"sum":15}`.

Right now, what i want to do is, when i run my ASP.NET Web API, i should be able to input parameters in the URL of the ASP.NET Web API (`http://localhost:55223/addition/9/6`) and instead of displaying result straight from Java web service, i want to use the function of the java web service in my API to calculate the sum of the input parameters. Does anyone have an idea on how can i go about doing that? What are the changes that i should make in my codes?

Here are my codes:

**ASP.NET Web API codes**

RestfulClient.cs

```
public class RestfulClient
{
    private static HttpClient client;
    private static string BASE_URL = "http://localhost:8080/";

    static RestfulClient()
    {
        client = new HttpClient();
        client.BaseAddress = new Uri(BASE_URL);
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(
            new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
    }

    public async Task<string> addition(int firstNumber, int secondNumber)
    {
        try
        {
            var endpoint = string.Format("addition/{0}/{1}", firstNumber, secondNumber);
            var response = await client.GetAsync(endpoint);
            return await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            HttpContext.Current.Server.Transfer("ErrorPage.html");
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

ApiController.cs

```
public class ApiController : Controller
{
    private RestfulClient restfulClient = new RestfulClient();

    public async Task<ActionResult> Index()
    {
        int firstNumber = 9;
        int secondNumber = 6;
        var result = await restfulClient.addition(firstNumber, secondNumber);
        return Content(result);
    }
}
```

**Java web service codes**

AdditionController.java

```
@RestController
public class AdditionController {

private static final String template = " %s";
private static int getSum;

@RequestMapping("/addition/{param1}/{param2}")
@ResponseBody 

public Addition addition 
            (@PathVariable("param1") int firstNumber,@PathVariable("param2") int secondNumber) {
return new Addition(
        (String.format(template, firstNumber)), String.format(template, secondNumber));
  }
}
```

Someone please help me thank you so much in advance.

Comment: What exactly is the issue and question? If you want to call the java service from web api, you are already doing that.

Comment: I want to be able to input parameters in the URL when i run the ASP.NET Web API

Comment: Then i want the ASP.NET Web API to display the sum of the two numbers like ` {"firstNumber":1,"secondNumber":1,"sum":2}`. The addition should be done using the function created by the java web service not by any new method created in the API itself

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> what i want to do is, when i run my ASP.NET Web API, i should be able to input parameters in the URL of the ASP.NET Web API (http://localhost:55223/addition/9/6)

Web API uses many conventions and if you play nicely then things work pretty well. The first thing you need to do is to rename your controller like this:

```
public class AdditionController : ApiController
{
    public async Task<IHttpActionResult> Get(int firstNumber, int secondNumber)
    { 
        var result = await restfulClient.addition(firstNumber, secondNumber);
        return Ok(result);
    }
}
```

You will notice a few things in above code:

1. The controller is called `AdditionController`. When you type addition in the url, the routing engine will look for a controller named `Addition` + the word `Controller`.
2. It inherits `ApiController` not `Controller`.
3. It has a `Get` action. If you make a GET request, the API routing engine will search for an action named `Get` or starting with `Get`. Thus it will find this action.
4. The action is returning `IHttpActionResult`. See my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46747937/4228458) for why.
5. It uses the extension method named `Ok` to return an HTTP Status code of 200. This is to follow good restful guidelines and HTTP guidelines.

You can call the above like this:

```
http://localhost:55223/addition?firstNumber=1&secondNumber=6
```

---

If you want to be able to call it like this:

```
http://localhost:55223/addition/9/6
```

Then you need to make some changes to the *WebApiConfig* class. Add this to code before the code for *DefaultApi*:

```
config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
    name: "AdditionApi",
    routeTemplate: "api/addition/{firstNumber}/{secondNumber}", 
    defaults: new { action = "Get", controller = "Addition" }
);
```

Above we are telling the routing engine: Hey routing engine, if the url contains the word *api/addition* followed by a variable and another variable, then use the *Get* method of the *Addition* controller*.

Comment: Hi, thank you so much for this answer. One of the best explanation :)

Comment: How do i call the java web service?

Comment: @susmithanaidu I thought that part was working already. Does this not work: `restfulClient.addition(firstNumber, secondNumber);`?

Comment: When i put that code into the AdditionController : ApiController, it does not work. It gives errors. When it is under the controller that i created previously (ApiController : Controller), it works.

Comment: When i use the codes in your answer, the parameters work fine. Only problem is that i get errors when i call the java web service.

Comment: Lets say i return the java web service using these codes: `var result = restfulClient.addition(firstNumber, secondNumber);
                return (result);`

Comment: I get error when i return the result. Error says `Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Threading.Tasks.Task<string> to 'System.Web.IHttpActionResult'.`

Comment: I have edited the answer. I thought you would be able to tweak the code to fit your needs and that is why I did not include the async part in my answer.