# how to serialize list object to json ?when I try to solve, showing some '\' inside the json result

Tags: c#, json, asp.net-web-api

code

```
public string getallcustomer()
        {
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            CustomerService _customerService = new CustomerService();

            dt = _customerService.Getallcustomer();
            List<Dictionary<string, object>> lstPersons = _customerService.GetTableRows(dt);
           // var json = JsonSerializer.Serialize(lstPersons);
            //return Json(lstPersons, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
            string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(lstPersons);

            return json;
        }
```

output:

```
"[{\"FirstName\":\"gateway\",\"PhoneNumber\":\"\",\"Balance\":-10.0000,\"CompanyName\":\"gateway\",\"Email\":\"1gateway@Sipkernel.com\",\"CustomerID\":1},{\"FirstName\":\"a-Office\",\"PhoneNumber\":null,\"Balance\":20.0000,\"CompanyName\":\"a-Office\",\"Email\":\"office@a.com\",\"CustomerID\":2}]"
```

Comment: https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/M_Newtonsoft_Json_JsonConvert_SerializeObject.htm this how it looks string representation of json

Comment: Looks to be a duplicate of [JSON.NET Parser *seems* to be double serializing my objects](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25559179/3744182).  Rather than serializing manually and returning the JSON string, return `lstPersons` itself (or some appropriate [DTO](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_transfer_object)) and let the framework do the serialization.

Answer (score 0):

```
i got the solution.successfully done.guys no need to serialize the list objects again.I can post the codes here.No need to return as string.
//controller





  public List<getallaccountDto> getallcustomer()
            {
                DataTable dt = new DataTable();
                CustomerService _customerService = new CustomerService();
                dt = _customerService.Getallcustomer();
                return _customerService.GetTableRows(dt);
            }

    //model dto

 public class GetAllCustomersDto
    {
        public List<getallaccountDto> accounts { get; set; }
    }
    //business layer

    //modified prince


   public List<getallaccountDto> GetTableRows(DataTable dtData)
        {
            List<getallaccountDto> customerList = new List<getallaccountDto>();
            getallaccountDto customer = null;        
                foreach (DataRow dr in dtData.Rows)
                {
                customer = new getallaccountDto();
                customer.Name = dr["FirstName"].ToString();
                customer.Phone = dr["PhoneNumber"].ToString();
                customer.Balance = dr["Balance"].ToString();
                customer.company = dr["CompanyName"].ToString();
                customer.Email = dr["Email"].ToString();
                customer.CustomerID = dr["CustomerID"].ToString();
                customerList.Add(customer);
            }                

            return customerList;
        }

   // this will return correct json responses.i have tested it with postman and swagger...successfully done;






 [
      {
        "CustomerID": "1",
        "Name": "gateway",
        "Phone": "",
        "Balance": "-10.0000",
        "company": "gateway",
        "Email": "1gateway@Sipkernel.com"
      },
      {
        "CustomerID": "2",
        "Name": "IPsmarx-Office",
        "Phone": "",
        "Balance": "20.0000",
        "company": "IPsmarx-Office",
        "Email": "office@ipsmarx.com"
      },
      {
        "CustomerID": "3",
        "Name": "khan",
        "Phone": "",
        "Balance": "23.0000",
        "company": "Test",
        "Email": "srk@king.com"
      }]
```

Answer (score -1):

That is because you are returning a `string` and the web api framework is serializing the `string` into JSON string literal so the entire thing is wrapped in double quotes (and quotes within are escaped using a backslash).

**Fix**

Change your action so it is returning `IHttpActionResult`: [This is better](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46747937/4228458) anyways in case you wanted to return an error or something else.

```
public IHttpActionResult GetAllCustomers()
{
    // code....
    return Json(lstPersons);
}
```

Comment: i have tried this code but again facing the same issue.my json  response have '/'.No problem. i have corrected my error.That i can post here.

Comment: @prince sorry I was not thinking straight. Try edited answer.